# Trouble downloading parameters for AlexaTM model: any suggestions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I don't know how to download the parameters of the model "AlexaTM": https://github.com/amazon-science/alexa-teacher-models

I have tried Sagemaker Jumpstart and I opened there the python notebook of the model. However, once I have the model_uri : s3://jumpstart-cache-prod-us-east-1/pytorch-infer/prepack/v1.0.0/infer-prepack-pytorch-textgeneration1-alexa20b.tar.gz (which should contain the parameters), I don't know how to donwload it.

Could you please help me figure it out?